# what's the format of numpy tobytes result when numpy array has different type?

Tags: python, c++, numpy

i want to save `pandas dataframe` into binary format so that i can read it in `c++`.

I tried `tobytes` method like this:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))

In [3]: df[0]=101.

In [4]: df['ticker'] ='nick'

In [5]: a = df.to_numpy()

In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[101.0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'nick'],
       [101.0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'nick'],
       [101.0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 'nick'],
       [101.0, 16, 17, 18, 19, 'nick'],
       [101.0, 21, 22, 23, 24, 'nick']], dtype=object)

In [7]: a.tobytes()
Out[7]: b'0\x0f@\xfc\xf9\x7f\x00\x000iME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00PiME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00piME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\x90iME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00pI\xe9A\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\xf0\r@\xfc\xf9\x7f\x00\x00\xd0iME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\xf0iME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\x10jME\xfa\x7f\x00\x000jME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00pI\xe9A\xfa\x7f\x00\x00p\x1dR\xf7\xf9\x7f\x00\x00pjME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\x90jME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\xb0jME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\xd0jME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00pI\xe9A\xfa\x7f\x00\x00p\x8f\xf8A\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\x10kME\xfa\x7f\x00\x000kME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00PkME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00pkME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00pI\xe9A\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\xb0\x14\xf8\xf7\xf9\x7f\x00\x00\xb0kME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\xd0kME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\xf0kME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00\x10lME\xfa\x7f\x00\x00pI\xe9A\xfa\x7f\x00\x00'
 ### !!!! what's here? both in binary or hex format, it can't be interpreted


In [8]: with open('a.bin', 'wb') as f:
   ...:     f.write(a.tobytes())
```

I can't read it in c++, here is my c++ read code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::fstream f("a.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
  if (!f.is_open()) { printf("open failed"); exit(1); }
  char buff[1024];
  f.read(buff, 1024);
  cout << *(float*)(buff + 0*sizeof(float)) << endl; // mess code, should be 101
}
```

i cant understand the byte output, it seem not 101 in binary or hex format, can you help on this?
what did tobytes do?

Comment: What don't you understand about the `tobytes` docs? "a copy of the raw contents of
data memory".  So interpreting that result requires understanding how the array stores it's data.  In your case `dtype` is object, so the buffer contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.

Comment: Your dataframe has two types of columns, one set with integers, the other with strings.  Originally it was made from a integer array.  That can be saved as readable bytes (8 bytes per integer).  But you added strings, which `pandas` stores as object dtype, pointing to Python strings.  Python strings are hard to work without outside of the Python environment.  It's that object column that forces `tonumpy` to create an object dtype array.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, if all data is int, that works, but with string, it failed, but i do need to save string at the same time, is there any methods?

Comment: Experiment with a  separate array with string dtype.  Byte string, 'Sn', will be simpler since it is 1 byte per character.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an `object` array, which holds a bunch of pointers to Python objects. Your `tobytes` output consists of a bunch of raw pointers. The data is completely unrecoverable from your C++, since none of the pointed-to data is preserved.

Comment: i see, so, is there any methods can save dataframe in binary format to let c++ read?